# gazebo_ros2_control does not load joints or sensors from URDF

Tags: ros-humble, ros2-control, gazebo-ros2-control

Following along with the ros2_control demonstration from ROSCon 2022, I am attempting to run [step 5, simulation in Gazebo](https://github.com/ros-controls/roscon2022_workshop/tree/5-simulation). The system successfully responds to Joint Trajectory commands, both through publishing a goal to the action server, as well as using the [rqt_joint_trajectory_controller package](https://index.ros.org/p/rqt_joint_trajectory_controller/), but the system does not seem to be operational for Gazebo. However, I have gotten the [ROSCon 2022 Controlko robot package](https://github.com/ros-controls/roscon2022_workshop/tree/master) to successfully load its model in Gazebo, so the issue appears to be with my URDF.

Launching Gazebo Classic is done with the following command:

```
ros2 launch linear_slider_bringup linear_slider_sim_gazebo.launch.py sim_gazebo_classic:=true
```

I receive the following feedback after launch:

```
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [84675]
[INFO] [gzserver-2]: process started with pid [84677]
[INFO] [gzclient-3]: process started with pid [84679]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process started with pid [84681]
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1710962513.742943224] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1710962513.743020949] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1710962513.743025336] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment flange
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1710962513.743027819] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment moving_base
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1710962513.743030104] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment tool0
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1710962513.743032301] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment world
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1710962513.982791564] [spawn_linear_slider]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1710962513.982982280] [spawn_linear_slider]: Loading entity published on topic robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-4] /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/qos.py:307: UserWarning: DurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL is deprecated. Use DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL instead.
[spawn_entity.py-4]   warnings.warn(
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1710962513.984899469] [spawn_linear_slider]: Waiting for entity xml on robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1710962514.111381248] [spawn_linear_slider]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1710962514.111706169] [spawn_linear_slider]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1710962514.618182119] [spawn_linear_slider]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1710962514.801764666] [spawn_linear_slider]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [linear_slider]
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710962514.816576069] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading gazebo_ros2_control plugin
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710962514.817868509] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Starting gazebo_ros2_control plugin in namespace: /
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710962514.817971930] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Starting gazebo_ros2_control plugin in ros 2 node: gazebo_ros2_control
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710962514.818000582] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading parameter files /home/user/ros2_ws/install/linear_slider_bringup/share/linear_slider_bringup/config/linear_slider_controllers.yaml
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710962514.819166614] [gazebo_ros2_control]: connected to service!! robot_state_publisher
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710962514.819530996] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Received urdf from param server, parsing...
[gzserver-2] [WARN] [1710962514.824922049] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Skipping joint in the URDF named 'joint1' which is not in the gazebo model.
[gzserver-2] [WARN] [1710962514.824944559] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Skipping sensor in the URDF named 'lim_switch_neg' which is not in the gazebo model.
[gzserver-2] [WARN] [1710962514.824972376] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Skipping sensor in the URDF named 'lim_switch_pos' which is not in the gazebo model.
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710962514.824985514] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'linear_slider_ros2_control' 
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710962514.825043669] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'linear_slider_ros2_control'
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710962514.825076663] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'linear_slider_ros2_control' 
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710962514.825081268] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'linear_slider_ros2_control'
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710962514.825083439] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'linear_slider_ros2_control' 
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710962514.825086273] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'linear_slider_ros2_control'
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710962514.825118472] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading controller_manager
[gzserver-2] [WARN] [1710962514.834426588] [gazebo_ros2_control]:  Desired controller update period (0.01 s) is slower than the gazebo simulation period (0.001 s).
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710962514.834576721] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loaded gazebo_ros2_control.
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 84681]
[INFO] [spawner-5]: process started with pid [84822]
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710962515.659723466] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1710962515.676665510] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710962515.677689805] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710962515.677986019] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[gzserver-2] [ERROR] [1710962515.705082392] [joint_state_broadcaster]: None of requested interfaces exist. Controller will not run.
[gzserver-2] [WARN] [1710962515.705154140] [joint_state_broadcaster]: Error occurred while doing error handling.
[gzserver-2] [ERROR] [1710962515.705205212] [controller_manager]: After activation, controller 'joint_state_broadcaster' is in state 'unconfigured' (1), expected 'active' (3).
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1710962515.715562559] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster
[INFO] [spawner-5]: process has finished cleanly [pid 84822]
[INFO] [rviz2-6]: process started with pid [84938]
[rviz2-6] Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[rviz2-6] [INFO] [1710962516.049478468] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-6] [INFO] [1710962516.049587327] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)
[rviz2-6] [INFO] [1710962516.065913352] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710963128.379637264] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_trajectory_controller'
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1710963128.402799383] [spawner_joint_trajectory_controller]: Loaded joint_trajectory_controller
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710963128.484252881] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_trajectory_controller'
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710963128.484424061] [joint_trajectory_controller]: No specific joint names are used for command interfaces. Using 'joints' parameter.
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710963128.484455242] [joint_trajectory_controller]: Command interfaces are [position] and state interfaces are [position].
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710963128.484473404] [joint_trajectory_controller]: Using 'splines' interpolation method.
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710963128.485896343] [joint_trajectory_controller]: Controller state will be published at 50.00 Hz.
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1710963128.487285184] [joint_trajectory_controller]: Action status changes will be monitored at 21.00 Hz.
[gzserver-2] [ERROR] [1710963128.503798555] [resource_manager]: Not acceptable command interfaces combination: 
[gzserver-2] Start interfaces: 
[gzserver-2] [
[gzserver-2]   joint1/position
[gzserver-2] ]
[gzserver-2] Stop interfaces: 
[gzserver-2] [
[gzserver-2] ]
[gzserver-2] Not existing: 
[gzserver-2] [
[gzserver-2]  joint1/position
[gzserver-2] ]
[gzserver-2] 
[gzserver-2] [ERROR] [1710963128.503825172] [controller_manager]: Could not switch controllers since prepare command mode switch was rejected.
[spawner-6] [ERROR] [1710963128.504372440] [spawner_joint_trajectory_controller]: Failed to activate controller
[ERROR] [spawner-6]: process has died [pid 91644, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_trajectory_controller -c /controller_manager --ros-args']
```

Most notable is the following line: `[gzserver-2] [WARN] [1710962514.824922049] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Skipping joint in the URDF named 'joint1' which is not in the gazebo model.` I am assuming this is the reason why the JointStateBroadcaster and the JointTrajectoryController are not able to load. However, I am confused as to why Gazebo does not like my URDF. The fully-formed URDF that is generated at launch time is as follows:

```
<robot name="linear_slider">
  <!-- World link -->
  <link name="world"/>
  <!-- ================== -->
  <!--     Properties     -->
  <!-- ================== -->
  <!-- ================== -->
  <!--     Materials      -->
  <!-- ================== -->
  <material name="alpha_black">
    <color rgba="0.6 0.6 0.6 1"/>
  </material>
  <material name="red_v">
    <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
  </material>
  <!-- ================== -->
  <!--       Links        -->
  <!-- ================== -->
  <!-- base_link -->
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <material name="alpha_black"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://linear_slider_description/meshes/7thlink_fixed.STL" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="1.0 0.3 0.10"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Gray</material>
  </gazebo>
  <!-- moving_base link -->
  <link name="moving_base">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <material name="red_v"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://linear_slider_description/meshes/7thlink_move.STL" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.22 0.202 0.118"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="10.0"/>
      <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.0915" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.975" iyz="0.0" izz="0.9915"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <gazebo reference="moving_base">
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
  </gazebo>
  <!-- tool link -->
  <link name="tool0"/>
  <link name="base"/>
  <!-- Frame for mounting EEF models to a manipulator. x+ axis points forward (REP 103). -->
  <link name="flange"/>
  <!-- ================== -->
  <!--       Joints       -->
  <!-- ================== -->
  <!-- base_joint fixes base_link to the environment -->
  <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <!-- joint1 -->
  <joint name="joint1" type="prismatic">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="moving_base"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
    <limit effort="10" lower="-0.4" upper="0.4" velocity="0.25"/>
    <!-- effort is attribute for enforcing maximum joint effort, between 0 and 100% -->
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
    <!-- Define where the joint will be located, defined in terms of parent's reference frame -->
  </joint>
  <!-- Extra joints for ros-industrial standard compatability -->
  <!-- tool frame to fixed frame -->
  <joint name="moving_base-tool0" type="fixed">
    <parent link="moving_base"/>
    <child link="tool0"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <joint name="base_link-base_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="base"/>
  </joint>
  <joint name="tool0-flange_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="tool0"/>
    <child link="flange"/>
  </joint>
  <!-- The caret ^ indicates to use the outer-scope property (with same name). The pipe | indicates to use the given fallback if the property is not defined in outer scope. -->
  <!-- ================== -->
  <!--    ros2_control    -->
  <!-- ================== -->
  <ros2_control name="linear_slider_ros2_control" type="system">
    <!-- Hardware -->
    <hardware>
      <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
    </hardware>
    <!-- Joints -->
    <joint name="joint1">
      <!-- Command interface -->
      <command_interface name="position">
        <param name="min">-0.40</param>
        <param name="max">0.40</param>
      </command_interface>
      <!-- State interface -->
      <state_interface name="position">
        <param name="initial_value">0.0</param>
      </state_interface>
    </joint>
    <!-- Sensors -->
    <sensor name="lim_switch_neg">
      <state_interface name="switch_val">
        <param name="initial_value">0</param>
      </state_interface>
      <param name="frame_id">base_link</param>
    </sensor>
    <sensor name="lim_switch_pos">
      <state_interface name="switch_val">
        <param name="initial_value">0</param>
      </state_interface>
      <param name="frame_id">base_link</param>
    </sensor>
  </ros2_control>
  <!-- ================== -->
  <!--   Gazebo Classic   -->
  <!-- ================== -->
  <gazebo reference="world"/>
  <gazebo>
    <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
      <robot_param>robot_description</robot_param>
      <robot_param_node>robot_state_publisher</robot_param_node>
      <parameters>/home/user/ros2_ws/install/linear_slider_bringup/share/linear_slider_bringup/config/linear_slider_controllers.yaml</parameters>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
```

Several other users with similar errors to mine didn't appear to have mass and intertia tags present in their links, but I have defined them appropriately. For more context, I have included my launch file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import (
    DeclareLaunchArgument,
    IncludeLaunchDescription,
    RegisterEventHandler,
    TimerAction,
    LogInfo,
)
from launch.conditions import IfCondition
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessExit, OnProcessStart
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import (
    LaunchConfiguration,
    PathJoinSubstitution,
    PythonExpression,
    Command,
    FindExecutable,
)

from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare



def generate_launch_description():

    declared_args = []
    declared_args.append(
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "runtime_config_package",
            default_value = "linear_slider_bringup",
            description = 'Package with the controller\'s configuration in the "config" folder. Usually, the argument is not set; it enables the use of a custom setup.'
        )
    )
    declared_args.append(
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "controllers_file",
            default_value = "linear_slider_controllers.yaml",
            description = "YAML file with the controllers description."
        )
    )
    declared_args.append(
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "description_package",
            default_value = "linear_slider_description",
            description = "Description package with the robot URDF/xacro files. Usually, the argument is not sset; it enables the use of a custom setup."
        )
    )
    declared_args.append(
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "description_file",
            default_value = "linear_slider.urdf.xacro",
            description = "URDF/xacro description file of the robot."
        )
    )
    declared_args.append(
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "prefix",
            default_value = '""',
            description = "Prefix of the joint names, useful for multi-robot setup. If changed, then you need to update the joint names in the controllers' description."
        )
    )
    declared_args.append(
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "use_mock_hardware",
            default_value = "false",
            choices=['true', 'false'],
            description = "Start robot with fake hardware mirroring command to its states."
        )
    )
    declared_args.append(
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "mock_sensor_commands",
            default_value = "false",
            description = "Enable fake command interfaces for sensors for simple simulation. Use only if `use_mock_hardware` parameter is true."
        )
    )
    declared_args.append(
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "robot_controller",
            default_value = "joint_trajectory_controller",
            choices = ["velocity_controller", "joint_trajectory_controller"], # add another here if we want to switch between different controllers
            description = "Robot controller"
        )
    )
    declared_args.append(
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "sim_gazebo",
            default_value="false",
            description="Simulate within the Gazebo Ignition environment"
        )
    )
    declared_args.append(
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "sim_gazebo_classic",
            default_value="false",
            description="Simulate within the Gazebo Classic environment."
        )
    )

    # Initialize args
    runtime_config_package = LaunchConfiguration("runtime_config_package")
    controllers_file = LaunchConfiguration("controllers_file")
    description_package = LaunchConfiguration("description_package")
    description_file = LaunchConfiguration("description_file")
    prefix = LaunchConfiguration("prefix")
    robot_controller = LaunchConfiguration("robot_controller")
    use_mock_hardware = LaunchConfiguration("use_mock_hardware")
    mock_sensor_commands = LaunchConfiguration("mock_sensor_commands")
    sim_gazebo = LaunchConfiguration("sim_gazebo")
    sim_gazebo_classic = LaunchConfiguration("sim_gazebo_classic")

    # Get URDF from xacro
    robot_description_content = Command(
        [
            PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
            " ",
            PathJoinSubstitution(
                [FindPackageShare(description_package), "urdf", description_file]
            ),
            " ",
            "prefix:=",
            prefix,
            " ",
            "use_mock_hardware:=",
            use_mock_hardware,
            " ",
            "mock_sensor_commands:=",
            mock_sensor_commands,
            " ",
            "sim_gazebo:=", 
            sim_gazebo,
            " ",
            "sim_gazebo_classic:=",
            sim_gazebo_classic,
            " ",
        ]
    )

    robot_description = {"robot_description": robot_description_content}

    _log0 = LogInfo(msg=robot_description_content)
    _log1 = LogInfo(msg=sim_gazebo)
    _log2 = LogInfo(msg=sim_gazebo_classic)

    robot_state_pub_node = Node(
        package = "robot_state_publisher",
        executable = "robot_state_publisher",
        output = "both",
        parameters = [robot_description],
    )

    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package = "controller_manager",
        executable = "spawner",
        arguments = [
            "joint_state_broadcaster",
            "-c",
            "/controller_manager",
        ],
    )

    robot_controllers = [robot_controller]
    robot_controller_spawners = []
    for controller in robot_controllers:
        robot_controller_spawners.append(
            Node(
                package = "controller_manager",
                executable = "spawner",
                arguments = [controller, "-c", "/controller_manager"],
            )
        )

    gazebo_launch = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([
            FindPackageShare("ros_ign_gazebo"),
            "/launch",
            "/ign_gazebo.launch.py"
        ]),
        launch_arguments={"ign_args": " -r -v 3 empty.sdf"}.items(),
        condition=IfCondition(sim_gazebo)
    )

    gazebo_classic_launch = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([
            FindPackageShare("gazebo_ros"),
            "/launch",
            "/gazebo.launch.py"
        ]),
        condition=IfCondition(sim_gazebo_classic)
    )

    gazebo_node_spawner = Node(
        package="ros_ign_gazebo", #"ros_gz_sim"
        executable="create",
        name="spawn_linear_slider",
        arguments=["-name", "linear_slider", "-topic", "robot_description"],
        condition=IfCondition(sim_gazebo),
        output="screen"
    )

    gazebo_classic_node_spawner = Node(
        package="gazebo_ros",
        executable="spawn_entity.py",
        name="spawn_linear_slider",
        arguments=["-entity", "linear_slider", "-topic", "robot_description"],
        condition=IfCondition(sim_gazebo_classic),
        output="screen"
    )

    rviz_config_file = PathJoinSubstitution([
        FindPackageShare(description_package),
        "rviz",
        "linear_slider.rviz"
    ])

    rviz_node = Node(
        package="rviz2",
        executable="rviz2",
        name="rviz2",
        output="log",
        arguments=["-d", rviz_config_file],
    )

    delay_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner_after_gazebo_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessStart(
            target_action=gazebo_node_spawner,
            on_start=[joint_state_broadcaster_spawner],
        ),
        condition=IfCondition(sim_gazebo)
    )

    delay_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner_after_gazebo_classic_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessExit(
            target_action=gazebo_classic_node_spawner,
            on_exit=[joint_state_broadcaster_spawner],
        ),
        condition=IfCondition(sim_gazebo_classic)
    )

    delay_rviz_after_joint_state_broadcaster = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessExit(
            target_action=joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
            on_exit=[rviz_node],
        )
    )

    delay_robot_controller_spawners_after_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = []
    for controller in robot_controller_spawners:
        delay_robot_controller_spawners_after_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner += [
            RegisterEventHandler(
                event_handler=OnProcessExit(
                    target_action=joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
                    on_exit=[controller]
                )
            )
        ]


    return LaunchDescription(
        declared_args
        + [
            _log0,
            _log1,
            _log2,
            robot_state_pub_node,
            gazebo_launch,
            gazebo_classic_launch,
            gazebo_node_spawner,
            gazebo_classic_node_spawner,
            delay_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner_after_gazebo_classic_spawner,
            delay_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner_after_gazebo_spawner,
            delay_rviz_after_joint_state_broadcaster
            
        ]
        + delay_robot_controller_spawners_after_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner
    )
```

Finally, here is my `linear_slider_controllers.yaml` file:

```
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100 # hz

    joint_trajectory_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController
    
    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

    
joint_trajectory_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - joint1

    command_interfaces:
      - position

    state_interfaces:
      - position

    state_publish_rate: 50.0 # defaults to 50
    action_monitor_rate: 21.0 # defaults to 20

    allow_partial_joints_goal: false # defaults to false
    constraints:
      stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.01 # Defaults to 0.01
      goal_time: 0.0 # defaults to 0.0 (start immediately)
      
    allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end: false
```

I do not know how to make my URDF compatible with Gazebo Classic. I know there are more Gazebo tags, but they do not appear to be mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tools like `check_urdf test.urdf` or `gz sdf -p test.urdf > test.sdf` to analyze your URDF. You'll see that the SDF which will be used by gazebo classic does not have any links: The inertia tag of base_link is missing.

Comment: This works, it looks like the controllers load. Why? I thought fixed base links didn't need inertia? Additionally, this didn't completely resolve my problems. Gazebo either opens a black screen, or it does not fully boot and Ubuntu asks to force quit

Comment: I solved this second problem by changing how I load the STL files into the URDF, as suggested [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/107438/37530).